# Pointer to the temporary string

Tags: c++

we have the following functions:

```
std::wstring f(const std::string& ref){
    return boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(s);
}

const f2(LPCWSTR p){
// use p
}
```

Is it safe to call:

```
std::string s = "x";
f2(f(s).c_str());
```

My doubt is raised by the fact that `f(s)` returns a temporary object and `f2` takes a pointer to it.

---

Dr. Memory points that it is "unaddressable access". When I replace it with:

```
std::string s = "x";
std::wstring s2 = f(s);
f2(s2.c_str());
```

Dr. Memory does not point "unaddressable access"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So long as `f2` doesn't store the pointer for later use, it's all perfectly fine.

Any temporary created during the evaluation of a sub-expression, exists until the end of the complete expression it appears in. So `f(s).c_str()` will be a valid pointer for the duration of the call to `f2`.

Comment: @user10121051 - Two possible reasons. (1) Your example is not indicative of your real code, and you do something ill-advised with the pointer. (2) Dr. Memory diagnoses a false positive. Not unheard of.

Answer (score 5):

The [temporary will remain valid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) for the duration of the full expression `f2(f(s).c_str());` - ie. that includes the `f2` function call.

This assumes that `f2` will not store the pointer to be used after the function ends.

Comment: @user10121051 : assuming you posted the exact code you submitted to Dr. Memory (ie. `f2` isn't doing something wrong with the pointer), I'd guess it's either a false positive, or intentional caution. Your alternative code is cleaner, and there's no issue with listening to Dr. Memory's advice in this case.